# How to Connect IP Phone Calls to My Web Page

Tags: webrtc, twilio, twilio-click-to-call, peer

Basically my Question is how can I create a Web Pages which will work something like this :
When a user will click on call button then that call will be directly transferred to IP Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It sounds like you are looking for [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js), which allows you to make phone calls from a web browser. I recommend you take a look at [the quickstart tutorial for Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript) to see how it works.